# How to do Url rewriting for folders?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite the link below

`www.website.com/folder1/folder2/index.php?name=value`

to be like this :

`www.website.com/folder1/folder2/name/`

I tried htaccess with this line of code, but it doesn't work.

`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteRule   ^name/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$   index.php?name=$1      [NC,L]`

Thank you  in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this rule in `/folder1/folder2/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder1/folder2/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ name/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^name/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?name=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you anubhava for your quick response, I tried your solution, but I still have the same issue .

Comment: I still have     www.website.com/folder1/folder2/index.php?name=12458

the index.php is inside folder2.
I put htaccess file  with index.php inside folder2.

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you enter: `www.website.com/folder1/folder2/name/12458` ?

Comment: ok now also try `www.website.com/folder1/folder2/index.php?name=12458` URL

Comment: just I needed  to specify the correct url . Thanks again  anubhava !!